# Giving unique key's to <li>'s inside of nested .map functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, unique, array.prototype.map

I have a function that requires nested map functions to work. This is because I am building a matrix grid question form. First comes the question, mapped from one array followed by a nested `.map` function for the possible choices for that question.

This works fine for the first row of questions. The problem is that the `id`'s for all of the `Choices` (i.e. agree, disagree etc) that I am assigning is only `1, 2, 3, or 4`. And then this repeats with the next question.

Because of this, all questions after question one, when choosing an option will only affect the first question. I need a way to continue incrementing the `id` number.

Here's an example:

```
Question 1: {id}'s to assign: 1, 2, 3, 4
Question 2: {id}'s to assign: 5, 6, 7, 8 etc...
```

Here's the relevant snippet of code. `params` is an object containing 2 arrays of data `SubFields` & `Choices`, they are what I am mapping through.

```
renderFieldlikert(params) {
    let matrixQuestion = params.SubFields.map(function(o, x) {
      let questionText = (<li className='left-column'><h4 className='text-left'>{o.Label}</h4></li>);
      let radioButtons = params.Choices.map(function(y, i) {
        let v = y.Score
        return(
          <li className='animated fadeIn'>
            <input onChange={(e) => this.props.handleRadioChange(o.ID, e)} type="radio" name={o.Label} id={i} key={i} value={v} />
            <label htmlFor={i}>{y.Score}</label>
          </li>
        )
      }.bind(this));
```

Comment: It's less that you need to increment ids, but that you need _unique_ ids for each key. One workaround is to import a library like [_uuid_](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid), and use that to generate the values in each iteration.

Comment: I don't know why you need the ids, but a lot of folks overlook the fact that you can tell which element was interacted with inside the handler function by using `this`.

Comment: I need unique `id`'s so that for my `<label>` I can point to the correct `<input>` field. Since I am iterating through the second `.map` function as many times as there are `SubFields` (i.e. Questions), I needed to find a way to make the numbers unique. Otherwise all choices, `agree, disagree, strongly agree, strongly disagree`, for all Questions, would be the same, `1,2,3 or 4`. See answer below. The trick was just using a simple counter and incrementing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple counter variable might do the trick.

```
renderFieldlikert(params) {
var count = 0;
let matrixQuestion = params.SubFields.map(function(o, x) {
  let questionText = (<li className='left-column'><h4 className='text-left'>{o.Label}</h4></li>);
  let radioButtons = params.Choices.map(function(y, i) {
    count++;
    let v = y.Score;
    return(
      <li className='animated fadeIn'>
        <input onChange={(e) => this.props.handleRadioChange(o.ID, e)} type="radio" name={o.Label} id={count} key={count} value={v} />
        <label htmlFor={count}>{y.Score}</label>
      </li>
    );
  }.bind(this));
```

Note though that this breaks the purely functional nature of the map functions (i.e. it's a side effect).  You may want to consider switching to good old `for` loops.

Alternatively, since the inner `map` is always performed on an array of the same length, you could compute the index explicitly.

```
renderFieldlikert(params) {
let matrixQuestion = params.SubFields.map(function(o, x) {
  let questionText = (<li className='left-column'><h4 className='text-left'>{o.Label}</h4></li>);
  let radioButtons = params.Choices.map(function(y, i) {
    var count = params.Choices.length*x + i + 1;
    let v = y.Score;
    return(
      <li className='animated fadeIn'>
        <input onChange={(e) => this.props.handleRadioChange(o.ID, e)} type="radio" name={o.Label} id={count} key={count} value={v} />
        <label htmlFor={count}>{y.Score}</label>
      </li>
    );
  }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Yep, I was just going to say that worked but had to include `count` in the `htmlFor`. As for the second addition. I am unable to, for reasons I don't understand, access `x` which is the `index` from the first `.map` function. I don't know why, either way the first answer you posted worked fine. Thanks!